# GCM Authorization Failed : WebAPI with PushSharp deployed on Azure website

Tags: asp.net-web-api, google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.android, azure-web-app-service, pushsharp

I am trying to deploy an ASP.Web API with PushSharp to the free azure websites available for 1 hour till 24 hours https://tryappservice.azure.com/ and I get a GCM Authorisation failed error. I am not sure if the free web site option allows this so that might well be the issue. I am passing in the right registration id received in my GCM Service on the android project for sending the notification & have verified that the sender id and auth token are correct.

Can anyone please let me know if this works on the free/shared websites. This [thread](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/49) on GitHub further adds to my suspicion that it might be the free shared website option which could be the reason

**UPDATE 1**
Felix on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036597/pushsharp-asp-net-mvc4-on-azure-woes-cant-connect-to-apns-feedback-service) has pointed out that the free/shared websites are a possible cause but again its focusing on APNS. Also thats quite an old post and Redth has been trying to get Microsoft to get  this sorted so I am wondering if this will be added at all. The work around it seems is to update the hosting tier to the next level which is a non shared server costing more

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I was using the 'Android' API key instead of a'Server' key from GCM,  creating and using a server key worked successfully on a free Azure plan.